# How would I get this to work - send to post from thick box

Tags: theme-development, jquery, javascript, media, thickbox

I have the following javascript which talks to about 6 elements. The first three open a thickbox  for media upload and what not upon clicking on a specified button, the last three target the input element that the src of that media should dumped too.

The problem I am having is that if I click on button `#upload-background-image-one` and then find a media I want, click "send to post" it gets inserted into: `#background-size-three` which is the third input. It should be placed into: `#background-size-one` but its not. in fact any button that is clicked to open a thick box media uploader will put the contents of "Send to Post" into the third input box.

So How do I target the specific input for each thick box that can be opened? (Which I thought I already was)

**Js:**

```
( function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Show WP Thickbox with image uploader.
        $('#upload-background-image-one').click(function() {
            formfield = $('#background-size-one').attr('name');
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
            return false;
        });

        // Take the selected image and insert only the src path into the text field.
        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
            img_url = $('img', html).attr('src');
            $('#background-size-one').val(img_url);
            tb_remove();
        }

        // Show WP Thickbox with image uploader.
        $('#upload-background-image-two').click(function() {
            formfield = $('#background-size-two').attr('name');
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
            return false;
        });

        // Take the selected image and insert only the src path into the text field.
        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
            img_url = $('img', html).attr('src');
            $('#background-size-two').val(img_url);
            tb_remove();
        }

        // Show WP Thickbox with image uploader.
        $('#upload-background-image-three').click(function() {
            formfield = $('#background-size-three').attr('name');
            tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
            return false;
        });

        // Take the selected image and insert only the src path into the text field.
        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
            img_url = $('img', html).attr('src');
            $('#background-size-three').val(img_url);
            tb_remove();
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're setting or overwriting the lambda function attached to window.send_to_editor three times.  The third time you're putting it in the element with an id of `background-size-three`, which if I read your question correctly is what's always happening.  That's why it's always happening.  I'm assuming you're calling window.send_to_editor somewhere else, maybe in tb_show()?

Comment: I wouldn't know as `tb_show()` and `tb_open()` are apart of Wordpress. Do you know of any examples on how to achieve what I am trying to achieve? using Thick box in Wordpress

Comment: Looks like you got it below, that answer looks like much cleaner js, good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to:

```
    $('#upload-background-image-one').click(function() {
        formfield = $('#background-size-one').attr('name');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');

        // Take the selected image and insert only the src path into the text field.
        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
            img_url = $('img', html).attr('src');
            $('#background-size-one').val(img_url);
            tb_remove();
        }

        return false;
    });
```

because when you click on a button you instantiate a call back function you can do everything in that function. Scope is then tied to that fucntion